# Adjusting Velocity according to the Yaw rotation of a Player

Tags: java, vector, velocity, bukkit, direction

How could I adjust the Velocity of a Player.
According to the Direction of the Player.
So when a Player turns with a certain velocity,
The velocity will change to the direction of the player.
So he could freely move around in mid-air, to any direction he would like

JavaDocs: http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/util/Vector.html

Comment: You want someone to write your homework for you? This is not the forum.

Comment: @OveSundberg It's not my homework. I'll add an example, which didn't work out.

Comment: You should be more specific. What do you mean didn't work out? What is the expected and actual outcome of your tests?

Comment: @OveSundberg I hope it more clear now. Sorry, it's quite tough to explain in in text.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Location class has a getVector method, which will automatically create a velocity vector based on the pitch and yaw of the player. You'd want to set the Y vector to 0 if you don't want them to just fly infinitely.